# AWS IoT Core - AWSIoTExceptions.subscribeTimeoutException

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I need to create a policy that will allow only the devices to connect that are registered into the IoT Core and also allow to the topics that are used in the job subscription.

Currently, I have a policy as shown below

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:ap-south-1:12345678912:topic/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:ap-south-1:12345678912:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
    }
  ]
}
```

On-device side, I am using the Python library to subscribe to the job as per the documentation https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python/blob/master/samples/jobs/jobsSample.py

The blow sample code I am using to subscribe to the topics that are present in `jobExecutionTopicType` class which is present in `thingsJobManager`.

```
self.awsIoTMQTTThingJobsClient.createJobSubscription(self.newJobReceived, jobExecutionTopicType.JOB_NOTIFY_NEXT_TOPIC)
self.awsIoTMQTTThingJobsClient.createJobSubscription(self.startNextJobSuccessfullyInProgress, jobExecutionTopicType.JOB_START_NEXT_TOPIC, jobExecutionTopicReplyType.JOB_ACCEPTED_REPLY_TYPE)
self.awsIoTMQTTThingJobsClient.createJobSubscription(self.startNextRejected, jobExecutionTopicType.JOB_START_NEXT_TOPIC, jobExecutionTopicReplyType.JOB_REJECTED_REPLY_TYPE)
```

The problem that I am currently facing is, my device client is not able to subscribe to the topic and I am getting `AWSIoTExceptions.subscribeTimeoutException` with current policy configuration.

If I change the policy like

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:ap-south-1:12345678912:*"
    }
```

then it is able to subscribe to the topic(s), however, it is violating the device connectivity condition. It is allowing any device to connect to IoT Core

Please help me in creating the policy which will satisfy both conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Avinash Deshmukh

Answer (score 0):

The resources in IoT Core policies are either a client, topic or topic filter ARN. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/example-iot-policies-elements.html)

This means that the topic example with a wildcard should be a topic filter. So the statement in the policy should be:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "iot:*",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:ap-south-1:12345678912:topicFilter/*"
},
```